# control the movement of LED with rotary encoder

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, led

I have 6 LED's in a row connected to an arduino uno and want to use the rotary encoder to control the movement. So far, I've have created a program that outputs the signals from the rotary encoder to the serial monitor, but I don't know how I should turn those signals into an signal for the LED's. My idea was to use the connect a certain distance of LED's (42 for each LED) and use large steps (like 1 turn of the Rotary Encoder (RE) is 5ish), but I don't know how I should go about that

```
example:
1 is on, 0 is off

LED start [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 ]
turn RE left twice [ 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 ]
turn RE right once [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 ]
```

My hardware design:
[image]
*(as the note says, I have a 5 pin Encoder, only a six pin was available)*

My source.ino

```
#define AAN LOW
#define UIT HIGH

int counter = 128;
unsigned long RealTime;
unsigned long CyclicTime;
const int pin_A = 2;
const int pin_B = 3;
const int SW = 4;
unsigned char encoder_A;
unsigned char encoder_B;
unsigned char encoder_A_prev=0;

void setup() {
  pinMode(pin_A, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(pin_B, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(SW, INPUT_PULLUP);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  RealTime = millis();
  CyclicTime = RealTime;
}

void loop() {
  RealTime = millis();

  if(RealTime >= (CyclicTime + 5)) {
    encoder_A = digitalRead(pin_A);
    encoder_B = digitalRead(pin_B);

    if(!encoder_A && encoder_A_prev) {
       if(encoder_B) {
          counter++;
       } else {
          counter--;
        }
  }
    }
   

   if (counter == 128) {
     digitalWrite(8, UIT);
     digitalWrite(9, UIT);
     digitalWrite(10, UIT);
     digitalWrite(11, UIT);
     digitalWrite(12, UIT);
     digitalWrite(13, AAN);
   }
    if (counter > 85) {
     digitalWrite(8, UIT);
     digitalWrite(9, UIT);
     digitalWrite(10, UIT);
     digitalWrite(11, UIT);
     digitalWrite(12, AAN);
     digitalWrite(13, UIT);
   }
    if (counter > 127, 5) {
     digitalWrite(8, UIT);
     digitalWrite(9, UIT);
     digitalWrite(10, UIT);
     digitalWrite(11, AAN);
     digitalWrite(12, UIT);
     digitalWrite(13, AAN);
   }
    if (counter > 170) {
     digitalWrite(8, UIT);
     digitalWrite(9, UIT);
     digitalWrite(10, AAN);
     digitalWrite(11, UIT);
     digitalWrite(12, UIT);
     digitalWrite(13, UIT);
   }
    if (counter > 212, 5) {
     digitalWrite(8, UIT);
     digitalWrite(9, AAN);
     digitalWrite(10, UIT);
     digitalWrite(11, UIT);
     digitalWrite(12, UIT);
     digitalWrite(13, UIT);
   }
    if (counter > 255) {
     digitalWrite(8, AAN);
     digitalWrite(9, UIT);
     digitalWrite(10, UIT);
     digitalWrite(11, UIT);
     digitalWrite(12, UIT);
     digitalWrite(13, UIT);
   }

  encoder_A_prev = encoder_A;

  if (!digitalRead(SW)) {
    counter = 128;
    }

    Serial.println(counter);
    CyclicTime = RealTime;
}
```

The issue with this code is that somehow none of the LED's are working

Comment: why not use the Encoder library?

Comment: `pinMode(x, OUTPUT);` for the LED pins is missing.
But I don't understand which way your encoder should control the LEDs.

Comment: pinMode is probably the best clue here. I do recommend breaking down your code and getting the simplest case working and then going from there. Can you turn on and off the LED (blink sketch) for example?

Comment: `if (counter > 212, 5)` is wrong. You need a decimal _point_ to get a floating point number `212.5`. This is unnecessary because you made counter an int. So `if (counter > 212)` is enough

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your goal properly: Do you want to "move" a lit LED in one direction or the other, depending on the direction of your encoder?
And roll over at the ends of your LED row?

Like this:

```
const byte leds[] {13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8 };
void setup() {
  // ...
  for (const byte & led:leds) pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(led[0], HIGH);
; 
void loop() {
  // ...
  if(!encoder_A && encoder_A_prev) {
   if(encoder_B) {
      up();
   } else {
      dn();
   }
  encoder_A_prev = encoder_A;
}

byte status = 1; // 1 .. 6 
void up () {
  status++;
  if (status > 6) status = 1;
  setLED(status);
}  
void dn () {
  status--;
  if (status == 0) status = 6;
  setLED(status);
} 
void setLED(byte status) {
  static byte oldstatus=1;
  if (status != oldStatus) {
     digitalWrite(leds[oldstatus-1],LOW);
     digitalWrite(leds[status-1], HIGH);
     oldstatus = status;
  }
}
```

// ... = *add the corresponding parts of your own sketch*